# Remote Desktop Gateway and HTTPS website on same server - possible?

Tags: iis, rdp, remote-desktop-services, bindings, port-443

We have an IIS server running a website with HTTPS access on the server already.

We need this server to provide remote desktop gateway services to other servers on the network.

Today I installed Remote Desktop Services. I used the same certificate used for the website. After I finished the installation, I got an error from IIS that somebody else is using port 443 (SSL) and the website cannot use the binding anymore.

Of course, that was the Remote Desktop Gateway using the binding.

Is it possible to use both services on the same machine? (one IP, one interface only) as I understand Remote Desktop Gateway must use port 443?

Thanks

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you want to do this?  Let's say your website gets hacked, the attacker now has access to a machine which can access the rest of your machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did eventually is encrypt and tunnel the RDP connections on both servers according to [this](http://blog.spencerkellis.net/2010/06/tunneling-remote-desktop-over-ssh-in-windows-7/) guide (using Putty and Copssh). We log in to the *internal* machines by RDPing into them from within the Webserver itself (We understand the risk here).

I also wrote a batch file to automate the login procedure. The script will terminate automatically upon logging off from the *internal* machine. (note: the ping command  delays the remote desktop menu, thus giving the user enough time to enter the SSH password):

```
start /b putty <user-account>@<ip-address> -L <local-ssh-port>:<ip-address>:3389
ping 123.45.67.89 -n 1 -w 12500 > nul
mstsc /v:localhost:<local-ssh-port> /f
taskkill /f /im putty.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.. But it has to be part of your existing website as you discovered that you can't bind two different sites to the same host name.  It requires a bit of setup, but yes, you can accomplish this using the same DNS name and/or IP.